show time slots after click on date calendar
I have two fields on Django Model, Date field and Time field,
class Appointment(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(
        'Section',
        verbose_name=_('Section'),
        related_name='section_appointments',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(
        'Doctor',
        verbose_name=_('Doctor'),
        related_name='doctor_appointments',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('Full Name'),
        max_length=255
    )
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name=_('Email Address'),
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        validators=[EmailValidator(message=_("Enter a valid email address."))]
    )
    date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name=_('Appointment Date')
    )
    time = models.TimeField(
        verbose_name=_('Appointment Time')
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True
    )

this model is used as form wizard consists of 3 forms ( choose section and doctor, then choose date and time, then fill the required patient info to schedule appointment)
when I come to step -2-  date and time, I wanna show a calendar with predefined dates ( from doctor profile) and also specific time slots for each date, how to show time slots after choose date from the calendar, is there any JS plugin for the same UI ? or If I wanna to create it from scratch how to do that?
I have attach a screenshot for what I've described

any suggestion from frontend prospective would be much appreciated.
